# Android Facebook Integration without Fragments

Tags: android, facebook

I am creating a social app and would like to have integration with Facebook so I can grab information on Friends, User Info, to Post on Users Wall and Upload a Picture to Facebook.  I have followed the tutorials on the Facebook website however they are all using Fragments.  I would prefer to not use fragments if at all possible.  I'm sure that Facebook wouldn't tie their API around the use of Fragments as that could shut out some people.

I understand the clear answer is to use the newest API with fragments however I would rather not do that for the following reasons:

- I don't see why you wouldn't be able to do it without Fragments.
- I don't entirely understand the point for Fragments and why they are becoming increasingly more popular.
- I have most of the application implemented without using Fragments and would like to implement Facebook login/use at this point in development.

That being said, how can I go about doing this without the use of Fragments?

Why are Fragments becoming increasingly popular?

If the answer is to use the Facebook API with Fragments, is there an "easy" way to alter the app I've already created, that uses Activities, so that it uses Fragments?

Cheers,

Jake

Comment: Fragments are used in general to work between tablet and phone sized screens. There are other uses too, but look over http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: There's nothing in the SDK that depends on Fragments. Any document that you see that references Fragments will also work with Activities. Do you have a specific implementation issue?

Comment: I believe my answer solves the issue of implementing without fragments (which is the title and main issue at hand).  Can you please mark as answered?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want a sample reference on how to switch your activities to fragments. I'm adding my example activity and fragments.

```
// Now this is the Activity class which I have to convert to fragments
TestActivity.java 

public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static EditText edittext;
private static Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_price);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_bold);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.equals(button)) {
        edittext.setText("Arshad's Test App");
    }
}
}
```

Now for converting the TestActivity to a Fragment we need to make it in two classes.          TestActivity.java and TestFragment.java

```
// Now the TestActivity will extend the FragmentActivity instead of Activity
public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private TestFragment testFragment_object;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        testFragment_object = new TestFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, testFragment_object).commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        testFragment_object = (TestFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}
}
```

Now the Fragment class will contain all the code of the layouts 
and actions to be performed in class which was contained in the Activity class earlier.

```
TestFragment.java

public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

private static EditText edittext;
private static Button button;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first, container, false);

    edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_price);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_bold);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.equals(button)) {
        edittext.setText("Arshad's Test App");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hey Arshad, so by looking at your fragment version.  The fragment version essentially acts completely normally... it just extends a fragment allowing it to be loaded as a fragment instead of an activity?  Also, if I have multiple activities can I make a fragment load another fragment?

Comment: Yes can actually use something like a switch case in the Activity class and change the fragments as per your need. In short you will need to have only one activity and the only thing which has to be loaded is the fragments.

Comment: Y down vote. May i know what's wrong with the answer. It is the accepted answer.

Comment: @Arshu It may be the accepted answer, but it doesn't actually answer the question.  "How do I integrate with Facebook without using Fragments? ... Here's how to use Fragments."

Comment: @Jules: It is very old post & now that almost everyone has switched to fragments. I believe using fragments has now become one of the standards. Also, even if I want to remove this answer I can't as it is the accepted answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Fragments, but I've implemented the Facebook Login button using an activity.

I just declared the button in layout

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id_login/btEntrarFacebook"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_bt_azul"
    android:layout_below="@+id_login/btEntrar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:text="f | Entre com o Facebook"/>
```

and in the activity:

```
btEntrarFacebook = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id_login.btEntrarFacebook);
```

The SDK examples comes with both Activity and Fragments implementations. The tutorials aren't clear enough, but the examples are way better than own Facebook manuals.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't found any of the tutorials that helpful as most of them are outdated or using fragments.

Answer (score 0):

There are many sites which will tell you about the advantages of using fragments over activities. One very important reason is that as the screen sizes vary a lot now with different devices, so using fragmnets we can utilize diffeerent screen sizes very well.

Changing activities to fragmnets is very simple as the life cycle and apis of both these components are alomost same. may be you can change an activity to fragment in 15-20 minutes :)

Give it a shot ..

Comment: So if I make the fragment full screen and then load the main activity or whatever into that fragment it will act just as an activity would, but I wouldn't need to resize the layouts for different sized devices?

Answer (score 0):

With fragments the concepts is like - There is a FragmentActivity. It is like normal fragmnets which in turn holds different fragmnets. I will try to explain you wih an example which is there in android developer site. Suppose we are working on tabltes. We can have a layout whihcan have left pane and right pane. Bothe panes are two different fragmnets. left pane will contain menu items and on clickin any item, right pane will show. since tablet screen is large we can show both pane on the screen and it will be easy for the user to use. May be like news application. But this design wont look good on small phone screens. in such cases fragmnets panes will automatically get divided into two screens and you can swipe between them. each pane will occupy full screen now. so without you doing anything, fragment takes care of screen sizes to adjust their layout. also normally in portrait mode, they are shown as tabs but in horizontal mode, they become drop down..

Comment: Hmm okay, my application will most likely be used on phones exclusively, however I do understand the reasoning for fragments.  They aren't necessarily faster in any way or anything though, are they?

Comment: Yes in scenarios it makes app faster as well. Once you replace each activity by a fragment, you can move between them by just sliding and few fragmnets are already loaded for you. Like normally you have 3 fragmnets loaded. The fragmnet whihc is seen and fragmnets to its left and right. In case of activity, you will have to launch one activity from another which will take time.. If you load things in your activity, it takes time to create activity..with fragmnets you can attach or detach them from fragmnet activity or move then to back stack.

Comment: Also another important factor is that, now android phone UI have fragmenet pattern including the home screen. So, your app will have uniform UI compared to phone which is suggested by app design guidelines. In such case, end users will feel easier and more familiar while using your app. trust me its time to switch :)

Comment: Hmm, I guess I should just dive in... haha.  Do you have any tutorials which you would recommend?  Ps.  I appreciate your input :) PPS. Thanks for not being an elitest jerk as some people are :)

Comment: Actually it has become so widely used, that you'll get a tutorial everywhere. few of them are : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html. Even android has given example code in apiDemos which you can directly pick and use. Also have a look at "ActionBar Sherlock". This guy rewrote the fragmnet logic so as to support lower phone versions as well and its musch better than Google fragments. It went on to become more famous than Google Fragmnets as it is more feature rich :) and finally google has even added it to their code base :)